# trigger when save a document in vs-code extensions

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

It was my first day to create a vs-code extension and wanted to trigger a function on-save.

I have gone through the documents and tried some methods, but it ended up saying "Found no documents"

```
vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument(() => {
    console.log('done');
})
```

Comment: Welcome as a new VS Code extension author! Can you give more information about what you exactly tried that resulted in "Found no documents"? Your code sample demonstrates that you are using the correct API in general. But it conveys too little context to allow helping you with your problem.